# Средства автоматической сборки программ

Tags: c++, c, сборка

Существуют ли средства для автоматической сборки программ, или же придется писать вручную такого рода скрипты? К примеру у меня есть проект на С/C++, и вот мне бы хотелось организовать сборку для него скажем на разных виртуалках (для Windows и Unix платформ), желательно еще и с различными компиляторами. Есть ли что-либо подобное для удовлетворения моим пожеланиям?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для Linux систем, традиционный набор таких средств называется "autotools" (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotools). Этот набор включает в себя три главных компоненты:

- *make* - система сборки групп программ, управляемая файлом *Makefile*
- *Autoconf* - Конфигуратор для системы сборки программ
- *Automake* - утилита для автоматического создания файлов *Makefile.in*

Утилита *make* автоматически определяет какие части большой программы должны быть
перекомпилированы, слинкованы, собраны  и выполняет все необходимые для этого действия.

Утилита *Autoconf* предназначена для облегчения описания конфигурации систем: хост-машины, на которой выполняется сборка программы и целевой машины, на которой будет выполняться собранная программа.

Automake - это утилита для автоматического создания файлов *Makefile.in* из файлов
*Makefile.am*. Каждый файл *Makefile.am* фактически является набором макросов для
программы *make* (иногда с несколькими правилами). Полученные таким образом файлы
*Makefile.in* соответствуют стандартам GNU Makefile.

Эта "святая троица" является стандартом де-факто. Практически 100% прграмм, предназначенных для сборки пользователями, имею в составе дистрибутива *Makefile*. И отсутствие его вызывает... скажем так - недоумение.

Написание *Makefile* для сборки простой программы тривиально.К сожалению, несмотря на все усилия, не удалось облегчить этот процесс для сколько ни будь сложных программ, состоящих из множества модулей, библиотек и т.д.

Поэтому, в последние годы, приобретает всё большую популярность система сборки программ *cmake*. Она имеет вполне приличный язык описания процесса сборки и доступна для освоения даже начинающими разработчиками. Есть, правда, одна *тонкость* - результатом работы *cmake* является всё тот же *Makefile* :-) Но писать его вручную вам уже нет нужды.

Так что, если Вы реально собираетесь делать некий **продукт** для *Linux*, настоятельно рекомендую Вам использовать *cmake*. Есть очень хорошая книжка на русском языке:

"Система построения проектов CMake". Денис Владимирович Дубров.

> Работа посвящена инструменту CMake, который является современной
>   системой для описания программных проектов и обладает богатыми
>   возможностями. В учебнике изложен материал, достаточный для создания
>   при помощи CMake проектов со сложной структурой, использующих внешние
>   библиотеки или вспомогательные инструменты разработчика.

Comment: ИМХО вопрос о другом: «как автоматически запустить данные утилиты  для сборки на несколько целевых платформ?».

Comment: @Fat-Zer **«как автоматически запустить данные утилиты для сборки на несколько целевых платформ?».** - для этого существует пакет *crosstool-ng*.

Comment: Я бы фразу про **cmake** вынес в первое предложение и выделил жирным.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, например https://travis-ci.org/ или https://about.gitlab.com/. Вообще, от языка это мало зависит.

Comment: Давно гитлаб научился С/С++ проекты собирать ? Вы можете заставить его запустить cmake, скажем, но сам по себе он C/C++ проект не соберёт.

Answer (score 1):

> Существуют ли средства для автоматической сборки программ, или же придется писать вручную такого рода скрипты?

Что-то существует, но какие-то скрипты написать всё же почти наверняка придётся (хотя они могут примитивными, уровня `./configere && make && make install`). А также скорей всего придётся [частично] самостоятельно создать среду для сборки. Хорошей отправной точкой для поиска конкретного софта, вероятно, станет [список в википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software), или просто поддаться влиянию имени на слуху и использовать [travis ci](https://travis-ci.org/), нсли нет доверия к сервису, то можно [запустить его локально](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21053657/how-to-run-travis-ci-locally).

> Есть ли что-либо подобное для удовлетворения моим пожеланиям?

Все пожелания какой-либо софт сразу вряд ли удовлетворит, что-то придётся сделать самому, научится работать с софтом, но как минимум любой софт из списка должен служить прослойкой между VCS и системой сборки, а также помочь организовать цели сборки.